# How to implement an action if an element is checked in MultipleChoice ListView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

How to implement a custom code whenever an item in a multiple choice list view is a listview is checked or unchecked? I couldn't find any suitable article on this.Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you. The following is my code for multiple choice list view.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayList<String> stateList =Handler.getList();
String[] catalogList = new String[stateList.size()];
catalogList=stateList.toArray(catalogList);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Catalog.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, catalogList));
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: @AdilSoomro it is I'm the same guy who posted that question. I've deleted it.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk I've attached my code. Please have a look.

Comment: I want to grab the state change in the checkboxes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add onItemClickListener to your listview , on item click check the state of you checkbox and do action you want.

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList<String> stateList =Handler.getList();
    String[] catalogList = new String[stateList.size()];
    catalogList=stateList.toArray(catalogList);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Catalog.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, catalogList));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = 
                    (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            System.out.println(
                    checkedTextView.getText()+":"+
                    !checkedTextView.isChecked() //because the onItemClick fired before checkedTextView change its state 
                    );
        }
        });
```

for why see [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml)

you also can do it by implement custom adapter. a dirty example following:

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //omitted
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     final int pos = position; // if you need positon in this item's action
     View item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_checkboxt, null);
     (CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // do your action here
        }
    });     
  }
 }
```

more effective of use adapter take a look this [post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)!

Comment: I used this code on a fast Dual Core android and the code broke 
!checkedTextView.isChecked()  because this no longer held true: "onItemClick fired before checkedTextView" seems to be different on different speed androids

Comment: DuoO that is not the answer.  this code relies on the speed of the event.  bad programming. 

this part doesn't work.  you have a major timing bug with this.. it works on slower devices, but doesn't work on faster devices..

!checkedTextView.isChecked() //because the onItemClick fired before checkedTextView change its state

Comment: Hi, @hamish I don't think it have a timing bug, all UI operation run on UI thread, single thread shouldn't have a multi-thread bug.This code is too old I sure it work on gingerbread but may not on newer devices. If you have a API >= 11, I suggest you use [CAB](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/android/listview/android-contextual-action-bar-for-listview-item-deletion-using-actionbarsherlock/)

Comment: take a look at what Shai is doing here... i think he is doing extra things that you missed... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841283/gmail-like-listview-with-checkboxes-and-using-the-actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Check the useful tutorial link below for generic MultipleChoice ListView. That should work for your case as well, I believe.

http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/