# Change textview and checkbox button color while listview is enabled android

Tags: android, listview

I want to change the check box button color when listview is enabled and other color when listview is disabled

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean when a `ListView` _item_ is enabled/disabled, correct?

Comment: i'm having a check box on top.If the check box is checked the listview is enabled.At that time i need t give a color for textview in listview

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer. May be it will help you

[Gmail-like ListView with checkboxes (and using the ActionBar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841283/gmail-like-listview-with-checkboxes-and-using-the-actionbar)

or just check this
[listView+checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821663/listview-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );

ListView lst = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_lst );

repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){


 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {

         if ( isChecked )
        {

            lst.setClickable(true);

        }
        else
         {
            lst.setClickable(true);
        }

    }
});
```