# Android: Listview like gmail where checkbox unselected shows a character

Tags: android, checkbox, gmail

I want to implement a listview where left most item of the row will be like gmail. It will show the first character of the row and on select it toggles to a check box which is selected. On unselect it goes back to the character. How can this be implemeted

Comment: I'm currently searching for the same thing, for now I have some pointers like for text drawable I'm using this 
https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

And for having actionBar stuff there is this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841283/gmail-like-listview-with-checkboxes-and-using-the-actionbar

But I'm not sure If it has to be this complicated we *should* be able to just change drawables of checkbox widget itself on checked/unchecked listener but I'll fancy that gmail's animation too.